# SNAFU with npm update -g

Tags: npm, osx-yosemite

I tried updating `npm` and all hell broke loose:

```
Environment check
✔ $HOME
✔ Yo
✔ Compass
✔ Ruby
✔ Git
✔ Node.js
✔ npm
dist: $ npm update -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/envcheck
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-h5bp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-mocha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-zf5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/headstart
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-foundation
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-h5bp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/envcheck
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-zf5
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/headstart
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-mocha
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-foundation
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yeoman-generator
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.14.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/envcheck/-/envcheck-1.1.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-zf5/-/generator-zf5-0.9.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-mocha/-/generator-mocha-0.1.6.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/headstart/-/headstart-1.3.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp/-/generator-webapp-0.5.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo/-/yo-1.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-4.1.3-nightly.2014.10.21.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-4.1.2-0.22.10.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt'
npm ERR! error rolling back  nopt@1.0.10 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Volumes/3 TB LaCie/* Projects/14-03157 Frontgate Windows App/Working/app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/.bin/nopt'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-h5bp/node_modules/yeoman-generator'
npm ERR! error rolling back  yeoman-generator@0.14.2 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-h5bp/node_modules/yeoman-generator']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-h5bp/node_modules/yeoman-generator' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob'
npm ERR! error rolling back  glob@3.2.11 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/resolve'
npm ERR! error rolling back  resolve@0.3.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/resolve']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/resolve' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-mocha/-/generator-mocha-0.1.6.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-mocha'
npm ERR! error rolling back  generator-mocha@0.1.6 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-mocha']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-mocha' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/headstart/-/headstart-1.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/headstart'
npm ERR! error rolling back  headstart@1.3.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/headstart']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/headstart' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-webapp/-/generator-webapp-0.5.1.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp'
npm ERR! error rolling back  generator-webapp@0.5.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-4.1.3-nightly.2014.10.21.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-zf5/-/generator-zf5-0.9.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/envcheck/-/envcheck-1.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/envcheck'
npm ERR! error rolling back  envcheck@1.1.0 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/envcheck']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/envcheck' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-4.1.2-0.22.10.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.12 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR! error rolling back  cordova@4.1.3-nightly.2014.10.21 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-zf5'
npm ERR! error rolling back  generator-zf5@0.9.5 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-zf5']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-zf5' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yo/-/yo-1.3.3.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo'
npm ERR! error rolling back  yo@1.3.3 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap'
npm ERR! error rolling back  phonegap@4.1.2-0.22.10 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap' }
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.1.14.tgz
sudonpm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@2.1.14 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Volumes/3 TB LaCie/* Projects/14-03157 Frontgate Windows App/Working/app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
dist: $ sudo npm update -g

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
sudo: npm: command not found
dist: $ npm update
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
dist: $ cd /
/: $ npm update -g
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
/: $ npm --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
/: $ where npm
-bash: where: command not found
/: $ which npm
/: $ envcheck
-bash: /usr/local/bin/envcheck: No such file or directory
/: $ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    797      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   800
sh: line 1: html: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'h: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
/: $ npm update -g
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
/: $ envcheck
-bash: /usr/local/bin/envcheck: No such file or directory
/: $ curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    163      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   164
sh: line 1: html: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'h: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
/: $ npm update
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Nothing is working. Not Yeoman, Bower, Grunt, etc. All from and update.

Did I do something wrong?

What should I have done differently?

What the heck do I do now?

FYI, I'm still learning Unix CLI so speak, slowly, please :-)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are on a Mac, but I see a reference to a Windows-style path in there. Can you confirm which OS and terminal you are running?

Comment: Using Yosemite. Terminal I believe is Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an upgrade fails due to permissions issues (which is what happened here... 'EACCES' basically means access denied), it usually means Node/NPM was originally installed in a location you need `sudo` to access. This is considered bad practice, but it is easy for beginners because `sudo` makes everything "just work" automagically, no matter where you install it. And now during the upgrade, you did not use `sudo`, which may change files you *do* have access to, while others throw errors and remain unmodified.

So:

*Did I do something wrong?*
Yes. Most likely, during installation of Node, you used `sudo`. By doing so, you caused most future commands to need `sudo` as well. But you did not use it during the first upgrade attempt.

*What should I have done differently?*
It is likely that if you had used `sudo` for that first initial upgrade attempt, it would have worked. The second time, when you did include `sudo`, failed because the first attempt (without `sudo`) destroyed your ability to use the `npm` command at all. So it failed for a different reason.

*What the heck do I do now?*
Re-install from scratch is the only reliable way out. And if you're up for it, try to make it work without using `sudo` at all. By doing so, you guarantee that future commands, with or without `sudo`, will have enough access permissions to have their intended effect.

To completely re-install and make your machine clean and shiny again, see here: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I highly recommend the approach using Homebrew. If you do attempt to use `sudo` out of habit, it will yell at you.